# A cipher brought to you by good fruit

Tags: word, cipher

> Wcev duqc. Vzq opqno cmd fakdxir. Cod gem cccf ks ofxq kdw riblnn. Uc'f vol jswbd kpmak.
>   Htwwjhy, tf l ahhq, rzwedl ydebr
>
> [image: fruit]

The image might help

> I used a vinegar fruit, a holy slob, another vinegar fruit, and rotated by 69 degrees. You must go back.

Comment: Hi @umsyt, welcome to the site! Please [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but I fear this one is not going to fare well. You may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for some guidance on how to turn a cipher challenge into an interesting puzzle. You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Comment: You might want to consider whether the clue should be considered a hint or simply made part of the puzzle.  Doing the latter could give it a better reception here.  Cheers!

Comment: The unfortunate part about this puzzle is that it's a multistep decode but there's no indicator that the solver is on the right path.  All that can be done is brute force all four operations for the guesses and hope that one of them comes out correct.  Particularly when two of the steps are clear guesses since we need to assume that the key the puzzle setter has chosen are spelled the same way.

Comment: @umsyt How do we handle the apostrophe in relation to the key?  Do we skip that location (ie only the letters use spots in the key).

Comment: @LeppyR64 the apostrophe doesn't make the letters skip. If you took out all the punctuation and made all the letters in to just one string, you could still find the answer.

Comment: I added a new line. When put with the text and decoded, it tells you how close you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> Banana

Method:

> Key Phrase = Htwwjhy, tf l ahhq, rzwedl ydebr
>  Apply Rot 21  = Correct, oa g vccl, murzyg tyzwm
>  Apply Vigenere Decrypt with Key "Orange" = Loelaoc, on a roll, zonlhg gsviv
>  Apply Atbash  (Atbash of holy = slob) = Olvozlx, lm z iloo, almost there
>  Apply Vigenere Decrypt with Key "Apple" = Plain text
>
>  Output = "well done. you found the message. now you need to find the answer. it's the third fruit."

I solved this with brute force on all fruits and rot values.  The puzzle was updated after solve with a key phrase that would indicate to the solver that they were on the correct track.

> [image]

Comment: That's exactly right.